# Remove non-ascii control characters from loading from json file

Tags: python

I have invisible control characters inside a json file (see below) from which I load like, but how can I remove them?

```
with open('test.json',encoding='utf-8') as json_data:
     data= json.load(json_data)
```

But now I have     text like

```
'help me\u00c3\u00a9r\u00c3 me'
```

Comment: These are not control characters: `00A9` is the copyright symbol, for example.

Comment: Where did this JSON come from?  It seems like it hasn't been encoded/decoded correctly at some point.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter out non-printable characters, you can do it like this:

```
import string
printable = set(string.printable)
with open('test.json',encoding='utf-8') as json_data:
    s = json.load(json_data)
    data = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x in printable, s))
```

Comment: Soory butz this gives me strange things as this just rpelace this without a whitespace...

Comment: For s='Unterstützung\xa0für mich..' yields: ''Untersttzungfr mich'

Comment: Also, german umlaute are not in printables?

Comment: Had the same problem, after implementing the same as @Albert suggests and came up with something like `allowed = string.printable + "äöüÄÖÜß"`, which is not generic of course, but works for me. Would be nice to have something like `string.typable`, containging all characters, which you can easily reach on typical keyboard layouts.